# Migrating from Matlab to Saddle: How to mutate a matrix selection?

Tags: matlab, scala, saddle

I have the following code in Matlab that copies over a subselection from one matrix onto the other namely it copies a slice of the rows between `i` and `j` e.g.

```
 % matrices
 matrix1(i:j,:) = matrix2(i:j,:)
```

I'd like to do the same using [Scala Saddle](http://saddle.github.io/doc/index.html) so I attempted:

```
 // matrices
 val matrix1 = Mat[Double](M, N)
 val matrix2 = Mat[Double](M, N)
 // ...
 // but none of these work
 matrix2.rowSlice(i, j) = matrix2.rowSlice(i, j)
 matrix2.rowSlice(i, j).toMat.toVec = matrix2.rowSlice(i, j).toMat.toVec
```

Is there a way to do this using vectorial subselections rather than iterating the matrices using indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found a way for my particular use-case but I think it should be no problem to generalize it. First of all, [Saddle's Mat](http://saddle.github.io/saddle/saddle-core/target/scala-2.9.2/api/org/saddle/Mat.html) instances are immutable, therefore it needs a different approach altogether. Second, `rowSlice` though it compiles for `Mat`, always throws an exception expecting to have valid indexes i.e. it only applies to `Frame` and not `Mat`, potentially a bug of the Saddle library.

My new approach was to collect all the sliced rows from `matrix2` into sequences of rows and then build `matrix1` as a new matrix at once from the resulting sequence of rows. Finally, since the `Mat` constructor expects a sequence of column `Vect` it has to be transposed too:

```
var RowSeq: Seq[Vec[Double]] = Seq()
RowSeq ++= matrix2.row((i1 to j1).toArray).rows()
RowSeq ++= matrix2.row((i2 to j2).toArray).rows()
RowSeq ++= matrix2.row((i3 to j3).toArray).rows()
val matrix1 = Mat(RowSeq.toArray).T
```